# Telerik Kendo UI ASP .NET Core Upload Inside Grid

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I tried to add a custom column to Telerik Grid for uploading documents, but I am receiving 0 files in controller.
I think it's because name of form input field is different than parameter I receive in controller, Telerik adds column name (Document1) to left of upload filed name, see screenshot.

[image]

And this is my controller, see the parameter is **file** but in source of HTML the input field name is Document1.file

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> SaveAsync(IEnumerable<IFormFile> file)
        {
            // The Name of the Upload component is "files"
            if (file != null)
            {
                foreach (var f in file)
                {
                    var fileContent = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(f.ContentDisposition);

                    // Some browsers send file names with full path.
                    // We are only interested in the file name.
                    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileContent.FileName.ToString().Trim('"'));
                    var physicalPath = Path.Combine(new HostingEnvironment().WebRootPath, "App_Data", fileName);

                    // The files are not actually saved in this demo
                    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(physicalPath, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        await f.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                    }
                }
            }

            // Return an empty string to signify success
            return Content("");
        }
```

But I can't add a dot to parameter in controller!

How can I force it to for example name parameter as Document1_file?

Comment: Maybe a Bind Prefix is what you need here. For example your controller action might look like this: `public async Task<ActionResult> SaveAsync([Bind(Prefix = "Document1")]IEnumerable<IFormFile> file)` or maybe look at the `Request` object to see if it has your file

Comment: Thanks, will try, but sorry I am newbie, where is Request object, is it global?

Comment: in your controller do something like `var form = Request.Form` and then debug and inspect that variable to see you form fields and there values